# How to turn off data formatting in table in time series data in grafana?

Tags: export-to-csv, grafana, grafana-templating

How do I turn off formatted data option by default so that the user can download the data as it is without any extra steps ? See the images for reference

[Formatted data on](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Fs8N9.png)

[Formatted data off](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DeRf4.png)